# Visio - Link to a page?

Tags: microsoft-visio

I want to add a behavour where I click an element on the page and it takes the user to another sheet (Visio page).

If possible, when sharing this with someone who does not have Visio, will the link work? I.e. PDF, HTML.

Answer (score 2):

In Visio 2007, you need to go to the `Borders and Titles` shapes and select a `Hyperlink button`, `Hyperlink circle 1`, or `Hyperlink circle 2` and add that to your diagram. It will show you a dialog where you can specify the target for your hyperlink. You can then set an absolute or relative hyperlink to any URL, document, page within a document, or shape within a page.

Within Visio, you have to right-click the shape to access the link (you can't just click the shape). However, if you publish your file as a PDF via the `File` menu, any relative hyperlink to a location in the same document will be retained and will work as you might expect.

View [the Visio 2007 help on adding a hyperlink navigation shape](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/visio/HP012315911033.aspx?pid=CH101778661033) for additional information.